# Have I setup subversion Repository Wrong?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, repository

When we initially setup version control we had very limited time and only basic knowledge how to set it up. We don't understand branches, trunks or tags. All we have been dealing with is Checkout, Update and Commit (oh, and the occasionally conflicts).

But now, we have gotten to a stage where we think we need to understand it better and probably rethink the way our repositories are setup and worked in.

Currently we have 4 different folders on our server which each contain a checkout. These 4 areas have the source code that is used for production. 2 of these checkouts are worked on directly as bug fixes checkout areas. The other 2 are used as development checkouts. Places where a team member may work on a longer development. Once they are done with the development they Commit it to the repository and thus the production code which will be updated to all the other checkouts.

But, when reading about branching it sounds like there is a missing level here. A trunk I think it what its called.

Can someone give this newb a bit of a quick crash corse in how to the correct way is to setup a repository for a team or developers who need a way to do quick bug fixes to production code but as well run a couple of developments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to read some articles first. Then come back with more particular questions. I think this is good article: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

In short, you manage your source code as a bucket of patches. Each change you made as a commit is a set of patches. Then you could compose these patches into particular product versions. Also VCS allows keep all history and provide you reproducibility of each published build.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way: you want a 'trunk' which is the master version of all your product code. But you don't want to screw this up by making changes to it all the time - one day you'll want to grab the latest version of the product and, horror, a developer is half-way through making changes that don't yet work. On top of that, imagine you find some problem with the latest version and you need to grab the last-but-one version (one you know works) instead.

Well, branches are the answer here. In subversion there are 2 different types of branch, called branches and tags. They're really the same thing but people call them differnet names to distinguish the use you put them to.

You have your trunk, as before, but now when a developer wants to make changes, you first make a copy of the trunk into a new branch. The developer can work all he wants on that branch safely. Once he's finished, you copy the changes back onto the trunk. Svn (and all the others) have tools to help merge the changes back onto trunk.

When you have a 'finished' version you want to keep, you do the same thing - you copy it onto a tags branch with a unique name (eg Release 1). The difference is that you never change this branch. It's fixed, constant and provides you with a way of identifying the code (and only the code) that made up that version.

That's about it. You can have multiple branches for development, and you can branch from a tagged release to make bugfixes or you can always branch from trunk to create bugfixes - how you do these depends on how you want to work.

Answer (score 0):

This resource explaining branches with graphical visualizations might be useful to you: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/